# How to write dataframe after converting vcf file to tidy dataframe with vcfR2tidy function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, vcf-variant-call-format

### Goal

Convert *`vcf` file* from genome of the plant to data frame.

### Code

```
file.name = vcfR2tidy(myfile, 
                      single_frame = "TRUE", 
                      info_fields = c("AC", "AN", "MQ"),
                      format_fields = c("GT", "PL"))
```

which runs successfully. However, when I try to write

```
write. table(vcfsmBO02tidy, 
             file = "vcfsmB001tidy", 
             append = FALSE, 
             quote = FALSE, 
             sep = "\t", 
             row. names = FALSE)
```

an error occurs:

> Error in (function (..., row. names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check. names = TRUE,
> Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl zeilen: 485723, 5

~ different number of rows.

---

### Picture of console:

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your question is rather unclear to me. Can you try and elaborate? You can edit your post.